# Python Opencv Can't get a degree symbol on videoframe

Tags: python, opencv, unicode

I've a small problem displaying the degree symbol `°` on a video frame to indicate local position.

Here is the part of the code, using Opencv with Python

```python
text1 = "4°30'30''N 4°00'20''W"

if ret == True:

    sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('UTF-8')(sys.stdout)

    cv2.putText(frame, " {}".format(text1), (10, 20),
             cv2.FONT_ITALIC, 0.5, (255, 255, 255), 1)
```

The output on the video frame is `4??30'30''N 4??00'20''W`

I've searched a lot in this forum as well as with Google, but all other codes I've used generate 
`UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xb0' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: First make sure you understand the [Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html). Then, what line is raising that error?

Comment: putText unfortunately can only display a very small subset of ascii, you'll get a '?' whenever it can't print your value.

Comment: Maybe you can get the symbol via QTfonts, you have to build opencv with QT support though http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dc/d46/group__highgui__qt.html#ga6281d0939583c9e0ee36372dfeb52ae3